# Flutter build error: Plugin with id 'com.mahmoud.katkotbot' not found

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 9S in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\app\katkot\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.mahmoud.katkotbot' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
```